# Would an OS create kernel stack for user-level threads?

Tags: process, operating-system, stack, kernel

In a system where the kernel stack is separate from the process stack.

Answer (score 0):

If the OS supports threads (as opposed to threads implemented in a library), yes it is likely to have a kernel stack for each thread.

In any protected system, the kernel stack is separate and protected from user mode access.

Comment: thanks for response, but I learn that the kernel stack does not know about the  user-level threads ..  why would the OS create a kernel stack for the user-level thread?

Comment: If you are talking about threads created using a library, the operating system only sees a process. That process has a kernel stack. If you are talking about stacks scheduled by the operating system, there needs to be a a kernel stack for when the process enters kernel mode.